# Delete two similar records

Tags: sql-server

Am very new to SQL so would like some assistance with a problem I have.

I use software to monitor files placed on some pc's, when a file is written a record is written in the database and again when it is deleted. I would like to delete any records that have both records. The table is similar to that below.

The action column shows 0 when the file is created and 1 when deleted

```
datetime       File hash value                       action
130213 14:33 | FDFGDFGDFGDFDFGVBVNVBNVBNVBNVNVBNVB | 0
130213 14:34 | FDFGDFGDFGDFDFGVBVNVBNVBNVBNVNVBNVB | 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.
S

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join to demand that there is a record with another action:

```
delete  t1
from    Table1 t1
join    Table1 t2
on      t1.[File hash value] = t2.[File hash value]
        and t1.Action <> t2.Action;
```

To preview rows that will be deleted, replace `delete` with `select`:

```
select  t1.*
from    Table1 t1
join    Table1 t2
on      t1.[File hash value] = t2.[File hash value]
        and t1.Action <> t2.Action;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea2f1/1/0)

Comment: Thank you, what would be the best method of seeing the result of the compare prior to substituting it for the delete? Just want to make sure that its getting the right information

Comment: Seems to work great, thank you for that. Can I ask another question relating to this. There is also another field in this table called "computer" It is possible to take that into account also? My problem is that if two different computers copy the same file and one file is deleted then the record for both would be lost. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Add a condition for `and t1.Computer = t2.Computer` exactly like the check for `[File hash value]`

Comment: select t1.*
from    table t1
join    table t2
on      t1.[hash_new] = t2.[hash_old]
on      t1.[computer] = t2.[computer]
        and t1.Action <> t2.Action

Comment: cant seem to edit the above again, how can i format so it make sense on this site? If I place "on t1.[computer] = t2.[computer]" I get an error

Comment: There's only one `on` per join.  If there's more then one condition, combine them with `and`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test (
    dt datetime,
    hv varchar(255),
    action int
)

insert into test values (getDate(), '123456', 0);
insert into test values (getDate(), '123456', 1);

delete a1 from test a1
join test a2 on a1.hv = a2.hv
where a1.action <> a2.action
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the files to delete in a subselect

```
delete from files
where file_hashes in (select file_hashes
                      from files
                      group by file_hashes
                      having count(file_hashes) = 2)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7e5a/1/1)

To see which rows will be deleted, you can use the subselect

```
select file_hashes
from files
group by file_hashes
having count(file_hashes) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could try the following:

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    CanDelete =
      CASE MIN(Action) OVER (PARTITION BY FileHashValue)
      WHEN MAX(Action) OVER (PARTITION BY FileHashValue)
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
      END
  FROM atable
)
DELETE FROM marked
WHERE CanDelete = 1
;
```

The `marked` CTE checks for every row whether the corresponding `FileHashValue`'s minimum action is the same as the maximum one. If it is not, the row is marked for deletion.

Based on that attribute, rows are deleted in the main query, where the CTE is used as the target of the DELETE statement.

The query assumes that `Action` is an `int` and can only be either `0` or `1`. If it is a `bit`, replace both `Action` entries above with `CAST(Action AS int)`.